# Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Tags: android

I'm trying to use an instrumented test and I updated my project to AndroidX. But I get the following error while trying to run:

```
2018-10-09 14:22:29.468 13263-13263/xxx.yyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.yyy, PID: 13263
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{xxx.yyy.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5730)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5728)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My test looks like this:

```
package xxx.yyy;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("xxx.yyy", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Didn't find class "**android.support**.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

You migrated to `AndroidX` but as you can see, *there is-are still usages* of `android.support` test libraries in your project.

To solve this, you should search for anything in anywhere in your project which starts by `android.support` and replace it or removing it to use `AndroidX` libraries.

Comment: Seems impossible to eliminate everything from an app, which starts with `android.support`. e.g. `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @Stefan actually, `AppCompatActivity` has its `androidx` counterpart: `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` :)

Comment: I didn't migrate to AndroidX but came with the same issue here. Any ideas? btw I have enabled multidex in my project.

Answer (score 70):

Inside the `build.gradle` file there you find the `defaultConfig` section. With the `testInstrumentationRunner` attribute the respective test runner can be specified. There the test runner from the `android.support` package might be specified:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

this has to be change to the test runner from the `androidx` package:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me

Comment: for me this just made the error in logcat disappear, but eventual result would stay the same.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the dependency as well, as suggested by @Daniil

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue when i forgot to add a dependency to the android test runner.
So adding this helped:

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was missing

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0`

in my case